# Express.js 4.8.0 Failing

Tags: node.js, express

Just installed express 4.8.0.
created an app by "express newAp" then "cd newAp && npm install"
when I issue "npm start" or "node ./bin/www" or  "DEBUG=newAp ./bin/www"

App is not getting started. It's giving error as shown below:

```
> newAp@0.0.0 start c:\Users\Somenath\newAp
> node ./bin/www


events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1039:14)
    at listen (net.js:1061:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1135:5)
    at Function.app.listen (c:\Users\Somenath\newAp\node_modules\express\lib\app
lication.js:546:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Somenath\newAp\bin\www:7:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

And is there a way I can go back to Express 3.x ?

Comment: Do you still have another instance of node running in the background? Something is still bound to the port you're trying to listen on.

Answer (score 0):

You have another program running using the same port. You can either kill that program or run express like this.

`PORT=3001 npm start`

Comment: Also you could change the default port by editing `bin/www` line 5.